# Getting "Subscript out of Range" Error on Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a vlookup code that shows the user description when they scan item barcode but I am getting subscript out of range error

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = Sheets("CONVERSION")



 Dim itemcode As String
 Dim description As String
 Dim myrange As Range
 ws.Activate
Set myrange = Range("A:B")
description = ws.Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TextBox1.Value, Worksheets("CONVERSION").Range("myrange"), 2, False)
 Label5 = description
```

Then it is supposed to assign the value of the vlookup (description) to the label

Comment: Which line causes the error? It sounds like the sheet name is wrong (amongst other things).

Comment: Set ws = Sheets("CONVERSION") I even tried to change the name to Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2") but still same error

Comment: That isn't even in the code you posted...

Comment: Also you are using `myrange` as a range variable and a named range.

Comment: sorry made a mistake on commenting  , I tried with both Just incase I made error on the sheet name

Comment: **1.** Is the worksheet in the workbook where the code is or in a different workbook? **2.** Check if the name of the worksheet doesn't have any leading or trailing spaces. The best way to check is to go to the sheet and double click on the sheet tabname

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CONVERSION") 'if you don't define the workbook it will be the activeworkbook
    Dim itemcode As String
    Dim description As Variant 'Defining it as variant won't rise an Error if the item is not found
    Dim myrange As Range

    Set myrange = ws.Range("A:B") 'If you define a worksheet, you can refer to it and you won't need .Select or .Activate
    description = Application.VLookup(TextBox1.Value, myrange, 2, False) 'as before, once you defined your range you can simply refer to it

    If Not IsError(description) Then
        Label5 = description
    Else 'if nothing is found description will be an error
        Label5 = "Item not found"
    End If


End Sub
```

`Application.VLookUp` instead using the `WorksheetFunction` will prevent VBA to rise an error in case nothing is found when it's applied to a `Variant` so you can use that little trick to later do the if I've posted you in case your BarCode isn't yet on your database.

Comment: i am still getting the same error "Subscript out of Range" on the part                           
     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CONVERSION") 'if you don't define the workbook it will be the activeworkbook

Comment: Where is the sheet you are trying to lookup? On the same workbook you have the code? Another one?

Comment: If it's in the same workbook and it's called "CONVERSION" there is no way this would throw you an error. Check the name of the sheet by double clicking it's ribbon and copy paste the name into the variable between the quotes.

Comment: i copied and pasted the name from from its ribbon but still getting the same error , i also tried it on another machine just in case and there is no change

Comment: Is the code in the workbook containing the CONVERSION sheet?

Comment: The url is not available

Comment: @Ghost still nothing on your link, can you check it before posting?

Comment: @Damian apologies the service I was using to host the files , deletes it after few minutes , I have uploaded [another](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/264a3be622058d94ff19db28a0b6745520190408130315/1abef6) this will stay 7 days

Comment: @Ghost as stated, your sheet is named "CONVERSION " not "CONVERSION" either delete the extra space on your sheet or add it to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Finaly Fixed the Problem , not the way i originaly thought but it does the job , i stopped using vlookup and did this

```
    Dim Found As Range
Dim str As String

str = Me.TextBox1.Text
Set Found = Sheet2.Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(str)

    If Found Is Nothing Then
      Label5 = "Not Found"
    Else
      Label5 = Cells(Found.Row, 2).Value

    End If
```

i found the solution [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/107454-find-textbox-value-in-column-return-adjacent-cells)